# How to change the bitrate of a stream in the middle of a filter chain

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

**Backgrond:**

I have an HSBS 3D video which is corrupt at some points, i.e. in some specific points of time, some frames are missing. Now I want to fix it (at least make it look better) in a way that I'm going to explain. I have acquired a 2D version of the same video which is intact. My plan is to remove the corrupted parts of the 3D video to the nearest key-frame, and replace them with the corresponding parts of the 2D version, after they are horizontally stacked (I call them "patch" here). Since I don't want to re-encode the whole 100 minutes of the 3D video, the patches need to be encoded similar to the 3D parts, and then concatenated with them without re-encoding.

The resolution, video bit-rate and audio bit-rate of the 2D video are going to be changed to be similar to the 3D's (1920x1080, v: 2113kbps and a: 95kbps). Other properties are alike.

The code I've been using is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i 2D.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=60:end=62,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=960:1080,split[v0a][v0b];
      [0:a]atrim=start=60:end=62,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[v0a][v0b]hstack[stv]" -map "[stv]" -map "[a0]"
      -vcodec libx264 -preset slower -tune animation -b:v 2100k -acodec aac -b:a 95k patch.mp4
ffmpeg -i "concat:3Dpart1.mp4|patch.mp4|3Dpart2.mp4" -c copy fixed.mp4
```

The above code works fine, but since the process of finding the precise moment to cut the streams takes a lot of trial and error for both 2D and 3D videos, I prefer to run every trial in a single line. So here is my question:

**Question:**

Is it possible to encode the above-mentioned "patch" in the middle of the filter complex, so I can wrap the whole process in a single command? Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "2D.mp4" -i "3Dpart1.mp4" -i "3Dpart2.mp4"
      -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=60:end=62,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=960:1080,split[v0a][v0b];
      [v0a][v0b]hstack,>>>BITRATE_CONTROL<<<[patchv];
      [0:a]atrim=start=60:end=62,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,>>>BITRATE_CONTROL<<<[patcha];
      [1:v][1:a][patchv][patcha][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" fixed.mp4
```

*The trimming of the 3D video is omitted from the filter complex, to remove the unnecessary complications.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Bitrate is an encoding parameter and has no relevance during filtering, which only operates upon uncompressed frames.
(Also, your proposed command is re-encoding the 3D parts as well.)

It seems better to use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org//ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) to split both the 3D and 2D video into a series of MPEG-TS segments using `-c copy` while preserving timestamps `-copyts`. Identify the segments with the corrupt portions in the 3D series. Identify their counterparts in the 2D series, then trim, filter and re-encode those. Codec, pixel format and resolution should be same, bitrate does not have to be. Then concat the old 3D + new 2D MPEG-TS segments into a MP4. Skip audio in these steps (`-an`). Once the final stitched video is ready, then mux the entire old 3D audio into the stitched file.

Comment: Thank you for clarification about filtering. Now I understand.

Comment: The segmentation of the videos (2D and 3D) will be the same? I mean every 3D segment will have a similar 2D counterpart. What if the 2D video is not synchronized 100% with the 3D (2D starts with a very short black screen and 3D does not)? Can I do anything better than trial and error to cut the exact segments?

Comment: You will have to set the correct time ranges in the 2D that correspond to the 3D.